# CasperJS script not finding elements with exists IT found using querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to create a scaper but i have serious issues.

Its a multi frame site and I'm just stuck now. I need to click on each h2,h3 or h4 in the left Menu Frame to load the right frame with the correct info to actually scrape useful data.

However, after I collected all the header ids, I can then never seem to access them in any way. this.exists calls show false, despite a list of 1042 IDs in links array.  What am I doing wrong?

This is my first try to use casperjs.

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();


function getHeaderLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('h2,h3,h4');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return '#'+e.getAttribute('id');
    });
}


casper.start('http://www.example.com', function() {

});


casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'phantomjs' search
    this.page.switchToChildFrame("MidFrame");
    this.page.switchToChildFrame("MenuFrame");

    links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getHeaderLinks));
    this.echo(links.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        this.echo(links[i]);
        this.page.switchToChildFrame("MidFrame");
        this.page.switchToChildFrame("MenuFrame");      
        this.echo(this.exists(links[i]),'found');
    }


});



casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion

});
```

Comment: I don't think that you need to add   this.page.switchToChildFrame("MidFrame");
        this.page.switchToChildFrame("MenuFrame");  in the loop. Try without this two lines.

Comment: That leads to no links being found at all.  The site has multiple frames within frames.  I could only access the links when I go to the specific frame.  But then exists doesn't work...

Comment: I mean keeps your first two lines and remove the lines in your for loop. In fact, in the loop you already are in the frame.

Comment: I;ve taken that out and its the same.  You are correct, that did not need to be there, but it has not made any changes.  It was originally there because on every loop it should have gone to a different frame to scrape the info from the main page, then back to the menu frame to click on the next menu item.

Comment: FYI, I turned on verbose logging and I get errors as such    [error] [remote] findAll(): invalid selector provided "570_572_612_-1":Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12  I have verified that 570_572_612_-1 is the correct ID

Comment: Why it's not #570_572_612_-1 ?

Comment: Sorry thats an issue due to my playing with building the string into different things.  I assure you the # was there in some case, not in others, the full h2#570_572_612_-1 in others, etc.

Comment: I did find that I can do this.evaluate(document.getElementById('links[i]') but that I still can't use that to click on the element...

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. If you can get the element in evaluate you can fireEvent on it. So create a function that will fireEvent.

```
    function casperFireEvent(element, eventType) {
        if ("createEvent" in document) {
            var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            evt.initEvent(eventType, false, true);
            element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else {
            element.fireEvent("on"+eventType);
        }
    }
```

Then on you loop you can do this :

```
   this.evaluate(casperFireEvent(document.getElementById('links[i]'), 'click'));
```

I'm not sure it it's conventional but that's a start.

Comment: No dice... TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'casper.FireEvent('document.getElementById('+links[i]+')', 'click')')

Comment: I forgot a parenthesis

Comment: I think the real issue is as follows.  I can't seem to pass parameters between javascript and casperjs.  I get undefined every time I try to pass a parameter.  All javascript function calls with parameters fail.  Does anyone have a good example of how I can pas a parameter.   this.evaluate(casperFireEvent(document.getElementById('links[i]'), 'click')); fails as does this.evaluate(casperFireEvent('document.getElementById('+links[i]+')', 'click'));  as does this.evaluate(casperFireEvent(document.getElementById('570_572_612_-1'), 'click')); and lots of other combinations.  All with undefined